# Automatically set the distance of keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes

Let's say I have an animation where every key frame is set on every 15th frame, after playing it I realize that the distance of the key frames must be shortened, to say, place all the key frames 5 frames earlier, so they have the distance of 10 frames. One key frame every 10 frames.
Normally, I would do this manually which is a time-consuming and annoying process, or I would select all the key frames and scale them down in the timeline.
Even with very accurate numbers when scaling them down, it can still happen that one of the key frames is set one frame too early or too far away, that it ends up on frame 23 or 26 while it has to be on frame 25 which can also break the even placement of the key frames coming after that.

It would be very comfortable if there was a function / feature that does this with exact int numbers, that you just select all the key frames you need, say " shorten distance of keyframes ", type in your int value of 5 in this case, and then they all automatically align evenly with the set distance on the timeline. This would speed up the animation process and make things way more comfortable than before.

Does anyone know if this kind of feature exists in blender or if there is a plugin for it?

Answer (score 1):

Just use simple math: in your example you have to scale the distance in a factor 10/15, wich equals to 0.66666.

So, set the cursor on the location of the first keyframe to scale, select all keyframes that have to be scaled and press S, X, 0.66666, Enter.